# Icons missing in applications

Tags: icons

I recently deleted some icon themes, as a result the applications do not display the icons properly. The applications are running but some buttons do not display some icons and some  icons are changed.

I tried re-installing the applications but the result is the same. Can any one tell me what I can do?

My available icons are.[image: Contents in the icons folder]

Application with missing icons......[image]

Comment: Provide us a screenshot of problematic icons.

Comment: @Anwar thanks for your cooperation. Actually i just installed the oxygen theme and it basically solved a part of my problem. Application icons are displayed. But when i run some application the icons are not displayed. For Example kolopaint application.

Comment: Are you happy with the partial solution? if not, please edit your question with a screenshot of the kolopaint application.

Comment: I have uploaded the kolourpaint application and it is still missing some icons....

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'theme'
```

ps: **replace** '**theme**' with exact **Icon Theme Name**